# Packets are disappearing

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, hp

I have a server HP DL180 G6, connected to a Cisco switch (4948E or 2960).
The server have 2 ethernet ports and ILO shared with data port #1.
ILO setted up to request ip from DHCP.

1) When I connect a notebook with Wireshark directly to port #1, I receive packets from two MAC addresses: Data Port and ILO Port, both sending dhcp requests.

2) When I connect a server to Switch (tested on both 4948E and 2960) and setup a SPAN monitor (mirror traffic to another port with the notebook with Wireshark) I see ONLY packets from Data port. There are NO packets from ILO port.
And there is no ILO's MAC in the Switch's CAM table too.
As a result, ILO can't get an IP from DHCP. And even when I configure a static IP for ILO - it doesn't reachable for network and NO MAC in CAM: Nobody know about ILO, even Switch. And yes, I tried to ping static ip of ILO with timeoud as result (no answer)

**So the question why can it be?
Why packets disappearing without any error?
And how to get work ILO?**

Can somebody help with this situation please?
I mostly want to understand, why can it be.
Thanks!

**Further a detailed information about environment and Wireshark dumps:**
All devices in 1 subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
All devices in VLAN 1 (ports on switch)
DHCP server locates in subnet 172.16.0.0/24 and reachable from server (windows)

**Catalyst 2960 (for example) ports config (all other config is default, after reset!):**

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/40
description here connected HP server's port #1 shared with ILO
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/41
description to notebook with Wireshark
!
monitor session 1 source interface Gi1/0/40
monitor session 1 destination interface Gi1/0/41 encapsulation replicate
```

**Port Gi1/0/40 statistics:**
C2960S-48-F01#sh int gi1/0/40 controller

```
GigabitEthernet1/0/40 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet, address is 20bb.c099.8a28 (bia 20bb.c099.8a28)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit, DLY 100 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, media type is 10/100/1000BaseTX
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output 00:17:22, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     2668 packets input, 475459 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 2634 broadcasts (1073 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 1073 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     86283 packets output, 85216496 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 6 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out

     Transmit GigabitEthernet1/0/40           Receive
     85216496 Bytes                           475459 Bytes
         1840 Unicast frames                      34 Unicast frames
        79351 Multicast frames                  1073 Multicast frames
         5092 Broadcast frames                  1561 Broadcast frames
            0 Too old frames                    5136 Unicast bytes
            0 Deferred frames                 143180 Multicast bytes
            0 MTU exceeded frames             326059 Broadcast bytes
            0 1 collision frames                   0 Alignment errors
            0 2 collision frames                   0 FCS errors
            0 3 collision frames                   0 Oversize frames
            0 4 collision frames                   0 Undersize frames
            0 5 collision frames                   0 Collision fragments
            0 6 collision frames
            0 7 collision frames                 337 Minimum size frames
            0 8 collision frames                1202 65 to 127 byte frames
            0 9 collision frames                 425 128 to 255 byte frames
            0 10 collision frames                656 256 to 511 byte frames
            0 11 collision frames                 47 512 to 1023 byte frames
            0 12 collision frames                  1 1024 to 1518 byte frames
            0 13 collision frames                  0 Overrun frames
            0 14 collision frames                  0 Pause frames
            0 15 collision frames
            0 Excessive collisions                 0 Symbol error frames
            0 Late collisions                      0 Invalid frames, too large
            0 VLAN discard frames                  0 Valid frames, too large
            0 Excess defer frames                  0 Invalid frames, too small
        10480 64 byte frames                       0 Valid frames, too small
        11860 127 byte frames
          502 255 byte frames                      0 Too old frames
         3276 511 byte frames                      0 Valid oversize frames
           19 1023 byte frames                     0 System FCS error frames
        60146 1518 byte frames                     0 RxPortFifoFull drop frame
            0 Too large frames
            0 Good (1 coll) frames
            0 Good (>1 coll) frames


C2960S-48-F01#sh int gi1/0/40 counters errors

Port        Align-Err     FCS-Err    Xmit-Err     Rcv-Err  UnderSize  OutDiscards
Gi1/0/40            0           0           0           0          0            0

Port      Single-Col  Multi-Col   Late-Col  Excess-Col  Carri-Sen      Runts     Giants
Gi1/0/40           0          0          0           0          0          0          0

C2960S-48-F01#sh int gi1/0/40 counters protocol status
Protocols allocated:
 GigabitEthernet1/0/40: Other, IP, Spanning Tree, CDP
```

**Wireshark dumps from situation #1 (when server directly connected to notebook):**
Here is a frame from ILO (ILO own this MAC address)

```
Frame 11: 342 bytes on wire (2736 bits), 342 bytes captured (2736 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{35063BE1-6696-40E5-918D-69EF24F97E65})
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: May 25, 2016 16:12:03.817712000 RTZ 2 (����)
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1464181923.817712000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.315021000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 1.358059000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 11
    Frame Length: 342 bytes (2736 bits)
    Capture Length: 342 bytes (2736 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:bootp]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_de:c0:50 (d8:d3:85:de:c0:50), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Destination: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Source: HewlettP_de:c0:50 (d8:d3:85:de:c0:50)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0, Dst: 255.255.255.255
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
```

**Wireshark dumps from situation #2 (when server connected to switch):**
Here is a frame from Data port (Port #1 own this MAC address)

```
Frame 78: 342 bytes on wire (2736 bits), 342 bytes captured (2736 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{35063BE1-6696-40E5-918D-69EF24F97E65})
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: May 25, 2016 12:58:20.776904000 RTZ 2 (����)
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1464170300.776904000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.005327000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 10.956572000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 78
    Frame Length: 342 bytes (2736 bits)
    Capture Length: 342 bytes (2736 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:bootp]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_dd:60:9e (d8:d3:85:dd:60:9e), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Destination: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Source: HewlettP_dd:60:9e (d8:d3:85:dd:60:9e)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0, Dst: 255.255.255.255
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
```

**Switch's CAM table:**
C2960S-48-F01#sh mac address-table interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/40

```
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address         Type        Ports
----    -----------         --------    -----
 1      d8:d3:85:dd:60:9e   DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/40
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 1
```

Comment: Is your server's NIC hard coded to full duplex, or is it set to auto?

Comment: Servers data port is all auto.
But ILO doesn't let to configure it: from manual i noticed that it works in 100 Mbps Full Duplex.
And yes, I tested with manually configured speed 100Mbps and Full duplex on both side (server and SW) - the same result

Comment: Sorry, a wrote this question after tests and copied stats after i disconnected cable and make a little mistake. So please don't see at this mistake: GigabitEthernet1/0/40 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect).
Of course it was connected and full operational while testing.

Comment: Set both the switch and server to Auto.  If the server is Auto and the switch is Full duplex, you will get a duplex mismatch.

Comment: You should have the speed an duplex of both sides set to Auto, not fixed configurations. Normally, an ILO port is a separate port from the data port. It doesn't make much sense for them to share the same port since the ILO is for out-of-band management.

Comment: @RonMaupin Lots of servers do this. It takes extra hardware (and license) to have a dedicated management nic. Sharing the nic creates many problems.

Comment: @RickyBeam, that really seems to diminish the value of the ILO. I don't think any of the servers guys in my company would put up with that. They insist on having an ILO port in a different switch.

Comment: @RonTrunk it was Set both the switch and server to Auto at first and situation the same.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'd like to use dedicated port, but the server does not have one. With Auto on both sides result is the same.